# Wordpress category header column not showing

Tags: wordpress, header, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce. While creating new product category there is no option/field as "header". There are Name, Slug, Description fields but "Category header" field is not available. I want to put banner in category pages.

Can someone help me how to enable this option to add banner above all category pages?

Answer (score 0):

While creating new product category there is option/field to add thumbnail image. You can upload your banner image as category thumbnail and make some tweaks into your product category template to display that image as page banner.
Refer image for better understanding of where to upload the image.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This option is already there, but I want add this column in adminpanel [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/LGbzfte.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by adminpanel? I am not getting it exactly. Can you explain more on it?

Comment: Please see this image, there is category header option in other theme but the theme i'm using there is not this category header option.. http://i.imgur.com/LGbzfte.jpg

Comment: It will possible with some plugin. Check [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-category-banner/screenshots/) plugin. May this would cater your requirement.